What is the PDF of distribution divided by a constant.
Suppose we have a random variable $b$ that follows a uniform distribution divided by a constant $a$ shown below as a new variable $c$:
$$c=\frac ba$$
The PDF of $b$ follows a uniform distribution:
$$g(b)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{(\overline{b}-\underline{b})}; & \underline{b}\le b\le\bar{b}\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Will the PDF of $c$ also follow the same uniform distribution as $b$ simply scaled by $a$:
$$g(c)=\frac{1}{a(\overline{b}-\underline{b})}\ \text{for}\ \underline{b}\le b\le\bar{b}$$
Is it correct? Any good reference would be appreciated. Thanks!

$c$ isn't a PDF because the integral is $\frac{1}{a}$. Change (scale) the bounds and you'll be fine.

If $PDF$ is defined for $(-\infty, \infty)$ then I don't think you can multiply by a positive constant $a>0$ because then the new $PDF$ will have it's area $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} PDF = \frac1a$

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} g(c) \, dc =1, \quad \text{where } c \in (\alpha,\beta).$$
First compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and since $g(c)$ is constant over the support of $g$, you should be able to compute $g(c)$.
